# Does operator ++ (int x) create new instance every time?

Tags: c#, immutability

According to MSDN, System.Int32 is immutable, and its members always return new instances.
Some common code, like for loop, requires ++ operation quite often.
Does increment always create new instances and discard the old ones? As far as I can see, this approach will severely affect the performance. And I wonder how Microsoft implements it.

By the way, is increment thread-safe? In documentation, it says all the members of Int32 are thread-safe, but there is interlocked.increment().

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you worrying about performance for integer increment?

Comment: @Juliet : Yes. I feel strange that value type like this is immutable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes and no.

The answer is yes in the sense that this:

```
i++;
```

is equivalent to this:

```
i = i + 1;
```

which would be equivalent to this (if `System.Int32` had a constructor with this signature):

```
i = new int(i + 1);
```

**BUT**...

A constructor for a value type in .NET is **in no way** the same as a reference type constructor.

The space for a value type is allocated once on the stack. When you write `i = i + 1`, this is simply writing a new value to the same location in memory. It is not a new allocation on the heap.

This is in fact an implementation detail; but that doesn't change the fact that the answer to what I think you're *really* asking -- "Does writing `i++` require allocating some new memory somewhere?" -- the answer to **that** question is no.

So, to clarify a few points:

> Does increment always create new instances and discard the old ones?

No -- this demonstrates a misunderstanding of the way value types work. It would only make sense to say that incrementing a value "discards the old one" if value types were allocated in some space other than the local stack. It is true that the old value is *overwritten*, but I hardly think you would find that surprising.

> By the way, is increment thread-safe? In documentation, it says all the members of Int32 are thread-safe . . .

Where the documentation says that all members of `Int32` are thread-safe, it means with respect to the current value. In fact, **any** immutable type is going to be thread-safe, because if it cannot be modified, then it cannot be corrupted.

What you must realize is that `i++` is not simply a method call on some `i` value; it is an *assignment* of `i` to a new value. This operation -- assigning `i` to a new incremented value -- is **not** thread-safe in the sense that two threads might both execute this code concurrently and you can end up with a new value of `i` that is only 1 greater than the previous value. That is what `Interlocked.Increment` is for. But the MSDN documentation is not lying to you; the internal state of `i` is no way compromised by multithreaded access.

Comment: Almost got what I mean. What I really want to know is what will the machine code be? Is it like INC(X), or do some complex operations to create a new integer and overwrite the old value (or even assign a new address in the memory). According to you, I guess it will be like INC(X).

Comment: @LLS: The closest you will get to the machine code is looking at the IL in Reflector. But most optimizations are done by the JIT.

Answer (score 1):

`System.Int32` is not a reference type. Instances are not instantiated by allocating memory in the way that classes are.

Instead, it is a *value type*. This means that the integer value is copied every time it is assigned to a variable. There is no reference to the integer, just the integer itself.

The ++ operator returns a new integer in a way that would be semantically equivalent to creating a new instance, but it doesn’t actually allocate memory for any object instances.

Comment: I this context, by saying the word "instance" I mean a value type variable on the stack.

Answer (score 0):

No increment (++) is not thread-safe.  The MSDN documentation is correct, but confusing.  You need to focus on the second portion.

> All members of this type are thread
>   safe. Members that appear to modify
>   instance state actually return a new
>   instance initialized with the new
>   value. *As with any other type, reading
>   and writing to a shared variable that
>   contains an instance of this type must
>   be protected by a lock to guarantee
>   thread safety.*

What is says is that `x+1` is thread safe, since by itself doesn't modify `x` (think of it as creating a temporary value).   But the assignment of `x+1` to `x` is not.

The documentation is also technically correct since `++` is not a member of System.Int32, it is a the C# compiler that translates `x++` to `x = x + 1`.

Comment: Thanks, I thought operator ++ should be considered as one of the members.

Comment: While not thread safe, Int32 assignment is atomic. If a race condition occurs, the last thread to write will win, you will never get a "mix" between the values.